# git push does nothing, on all apps

Tags: git, github

Ran into an odd situation.  Git push just stopped doing anything, for all my apps.  I can run the command, it just does not do anything, no error either.

Samples code from one app below, everything looked normal to me.

remote origin command returns

```
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: http://github.com/rockwellwindsor/mediatable.git
  Push  URL: http://github.com/rockwellwindsor/mediatable.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    master tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
     master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (fast-forwardable)
```

git pull works normal

config is

```
[core]
repositoryformatversion = 0
filemode = true
bare = false
logallrefupdates = true
ignorecase = true
precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = http://github.com/rockwellwindsor/mediatable.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

This is happening with all my apps so It has to be some setting I messed up or something.  Any ideas how to debug this?

Comment: What happens when you run `git push`? Is there any output at all? What if you first set `GIT_TRACE=1` to enable debugging output; does this yield anything useful?  (e.g., run `GIT_TRACE=1 git push`)

Comment: Wow that was odd, I ran that command, it asked for credentials and then push worked, if you put is as an answer I will accept it.  I guess at some point I stopped allowing credentials to be accessed or something.

Comment: That's very kind of you, but I would feel guilty posting that as an answer since it was really just a diagnostic step. Glad it seems to have helped out!